# Azure Data Studio select correct encoding

Tags: sql, azure-data-studio

I have a problem with encoding in ADS. I set in all settings encoding on "UTF-8 with boom". And when I open a new query then ok "UTF-8 with boom" encoding is set but when I open some files with my T-sql store procedures then always azure data studio open it with "UTF-8" encoding without boom.
How to fix that?

Comment: What do you mean you open the files with your store procedure?

Comment: I have a file .sql with some t-sql code. And when I click on it in my desktop and I select "open with" and next I choose Azure Data Studio then my file will be open in Azure Data Studio but encoding will be UTF-8 not UTF-8 with boom. I don't have this problem in sql server managment studio. It always open's my files with   UTF-8 with boom encoding.

Comment: Sounds like you have a setting that is overriding the (presumably) User setting. Is the file in a Project/Workspace or directory with its own settings? Those will take precedence over user settings.

Comment: It is in the git repository directory.

Comment: And does that directory have a settings file for ADS?

Comment: No, I didn't find that file.

Answer (score 0):

Goto settings, search for encoding, change Files: Enconding to "UTF-8 with boom"

Comment: uh... I think you mean "BOM"?